# Unable to login to a local MediaWiki instance after having created a new user with the createAndPromote maintenance script

Tags: mediawiki

I'm running a local MediaWiki instance in a container and everything looks fine except for the creation of user accounts.

I'm using the following command to create a new account:

```bash
docker exec -it mediawiki-mediawiki-1 php /var/www/html/maintenance/run.php createAndPromote --force --sysop --bureaucrat --interface-admin New.Username change_password
wiki: Creating and promoting User:New.Username into sysop, bureaucrat, interface-admin...
done.
docker exec -it mediawiki-mediawiki-1 php /var/www/html/maintenance/run.php resetUserEmail New.Username New.Username@gmail.at
Done!
```

Everything looks ok, but trying to login I get the error: `Incorrect username or password entered. Please try again.`.

What am I missing or how can I debug this problem?

MediaWiki: 1.40.0
PHP: 8.1.22
ICU: 72.1
MariaDB: 11.0.3-MariaDB-1:11.0.3+maria~ubu2204

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resetUserEmail.php` (without the `--no-reset-password` flag) sets a random password, as the script is normally used in the case of malicious account takeovers.

Comment: I completely missed this. Thank you!